# Use the Windows raw access APIs to directly access the USB drive

Tags: usb

At the end of USB physical drive, I want to write data directly using windows raw access API. I don't want to use kernel driver to do that.

As far as I know, HDD direct access is blocked from windows xp sp2 or sp3(?) for security reason. I'm not sure this is true for USB drive.

Please guide me how to get there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question seems to be related to software development.  I voted to move this to a more suitable web site, but my only option was to close this question in order to make this happen.  Hopefully it will be opened at the new site?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how "direct" you want to be.

Something like

```
HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile("\\\\.\\F:", ...);
ReadFile(hDrive, ...);
```

should get you what you need in most situations, although you might need `DeviceIoControl` with

- [`IOCTL_USB_USER_REQUEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537344%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with `USBUSER_PASS_THRU`
- [`IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- or [`IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

if you're doing something really advanced.

P.S.: This should be on StackOverflow, as other people have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Voted to move to Stack Overflow. I think regardless, using an external HDD connected by USB won't change anything, as it still appears as a normal disk to windows.

When you say "raw access API", do you mean functions like CreateFile, WriteFile etc as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? Because those functions should be able to be called from normal Win32 apps. Or do you want direct access to the disk itself, with no filesystem layer in between? (Some user apps such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) can directly *open* disks for reading/writing - use with caution)